# Rendering math with KaTex

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, katex

I download the latest katex build release [here](https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX). I'm trying to integrate it into my electron project. As a beginner developer, I'm having trouble achieving what I want.

The following code renders (one line of code) the string `"c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}"` in a `div` with a class of `theorem`.

```
const theorem = document.querySelector('.theorem');

katex.render("c = \\pm\\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}", theorem, {
   throwOnError: false
});
```

How would I render the following

```
\begin{Bmatrix}

   a & b \\

   c & d

\end{Bmatrix}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const matrix = document.querySelector('.matrix');

katex.render("\\begin{Bmatrix}\n\n   a & b \\\\\n\n   c & d\n\n\\end{Bmatrix}", matrix, {
   throwOnError: false
});
```